# Where are the Joomla / Drupal input validation scripts located?

Tags: php, security, drupal, joomla

I would like to see how Joomla / Drupal do their validation / security, where are the input validation scripts located?

Comment: It would be better to ask two different questions; Joomla and Drupal don't use the same code.

Comment: Probably, but just in case someone passing by knows either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a single/central validation code for user's input in Drupal. Each form as it own validations handlers, [search for *_validate* in the Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/_validate). In addition, there is some re-usable validation functions such as [`valid_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/valid_url/6) and [`valid_email_address()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/valid_email_address/6). Drupal also encourage output sanitization with functions such as [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/6), [`check_plain()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_plain/6) or [`filter_xss()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_xss/6). Drupal discourage bad-practive regarding SQL injection by favoring placeholders in query string, see [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query/6).

Answer (score 0):

Drupal: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/6

Joomla: http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/User/_joomla---user---authentication.php.html